# Is transactional task dequeuing supported?

Tags: google-app-engine

This [section](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions.html#Transactional_Task_Enqueuing) describes how to enqueue tasks in the scope of a transaction that modifies an entity group. It mentions that this is useful for modifying other entity groups outside of the transaction. However, I haven't found a matching section on transactional task dequeue. Is this supported?

The underlying question is whether it is possible to use the Task Queue Service to achieve the same result as cross-group transactions in decoupled manner.